# Is it possible to share a PostgreSQL database between Windows and Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql

Is it possible to use a PostrgeSQL database in Windows and use the same one in Linux after rebooting? Will pointing the data folder to a common folder be sufficient?

I know I could test it and then see for myself, but if someone has a better idea, I'm all ears!

Comment: You can use a VM that is on a folder shared by both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL data files are operating system and CPU architecture specific.  So first of all your Linux and Windows systems would need to be of the same architecture.  And then the data layout that the compilers use would need to be the same as well.  I have tried this in the past between Linux and Cygwin, and it did *not* work.  So I would be very surprised if it worked between Linux and native Windows.  In general, don't count on it.

Comment: I also noticed that locales such as `en_US.UTF8` is not supported on Windows. Such a pity, I've successfully shared MongoDB data folder between Linux and Windows in my dual-boot system.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very surprised if it worked.

Why not just run a virtual machine when you've booted up with the non-native OS?